# Apache CXF(with spring boot) How can I return original WSDL file(not generated by cxf)?

Tags: java, spring, wsdl, cxf, spring-ws

I have `WSDL` and `XSD` schemas. I generate `java classes` and `service interface` from it with `CXF`.

I create SOAP endpoint with CXF:

```
@Bean
Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, myEndpoint);
    endpoint.publish(path);
    return endpoint;
}
```

When I open service URl I get generated WSDL but I need Original WSDl.

How can I return `original WSDL` and not generated?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it seems not doable (or not quite easy) as Apache CXF publishes a WS endpoint based on its implementation (and/or relevant generated sources for XML schemas). CXF does not directly used the WSDL and XSDs, and therefore, the endpoint's WSDL might be a tad different from the original WSDL.

I have used `cxf-codegen-plugin` to generate Java code from WSDL+XSD, then implemented the business logics of each service and publish them using Apache CXF [`<jax-ws>`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws.html). The generated code are well annotated so that it seems JAX-WS can use these annotations to produce very close results. The published WSDLs are only slightly different from the original WSDLs but hard to notice if not expert. You can find the project's source here: https://github.com/htr3n/loan-approval-portal.

Perhaps, the closest you might have is using Spring WS with [`<static-wsdl>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure).